# obsolete WCF method

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF web service which I have to update. Because of that, I would like to flag some methods obsolete. If the client reference a dll, it works. If the clients reference the web service with the WSDL file, the warning does not come to the client.

My question is: Does anyone know a way I can inform the client about the fact that the method will be delete in the next versions or how I can send the warning with the WSDL file for the client?

If someone has a solution in a completely different direction, please tell me.

The methods to remove isn't an option.

The methods are defined as follows:

```
   <Operation Contract ()>
    Function method (param As String) As String
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I now there are no way of doing that other than contacting the developers directly.

You also might want to look at data contract versioning. Not something I have done myself, but you can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The Information on the linked site, doesn’t helped me, because that not the correct situation. I can contact the developer directly, but I wish me a possibility to support the update process.

Comment: In WCF you are free to extent. Extending will not break backwards compatibility. If you do breaking changes you would have to create a copy of the api and call it v2: `host:81/api/somepath` and `host:81/api/v2/somepath`.

Comment: So to sum up, you cannot do what you want. It is not a problem with WCF, but something that WSDL and the SOAP envelope just doesn't support. Remember that WCF service can also be called from a JAVA client.